# Override itemrender in block - Magento

Tags: magento

I'm new to Magento, so sry if it's a newbie question

Basically there is a block declared as follows in a layout.xml file:

```
<block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
     <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
     <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
     <action method="chooseTemplate"/>
     <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
     <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
     <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
```

I would like to override `<action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>` with a custom template.

Since a method is being called over here, how could the template be changed?

Thanks a lot!

Krt_Malta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In you module layout file or local.xml

```
<reference name="checkout.cart">
   <action method="addItemRender">
      <type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>path/to/your/item/default.phtml</template>
   </action>
</reference>
```

The path to template file is relative to your theme template folder

You may want to check
http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/the-better-way-to-modify-magento-layout